# SonarLint plugin misses some (SonarCloud's) rules locally

Tags: vscode-extensions, sonarlint, sonarcloud, sonarlint-vs

***TL;DR*** -> Force `code smells` to apear as **SonarCloud** issues on IDE

I got **SonarLint** plugin (vscode) installed locally and configured with external **SonarCloud** rules (by my organization's project).
The thing is even though it is well configured, some issues fail to count as an acttual issue locally on my IDE and only apears online (e.g. github integration).

I have not yet realized what is common between those slippery sonarcloud issues, might be `code smells`.

I have seen some StackOverflow questions regarding that matter, but have not yet encountered an answer which explicitly suggests a workaround or a method to configure it as I wish.

Did anyone ever manage to work it out?